# Mobile Safari, Rails 4, Bootstrap 3: JQuery Datepicker and separate JS/Ajax code not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

A peculiar thing is happening on a site I'm working on. When accessing the site for the first time, it is in Bootstrap "Responsive" mode (everything is nice and large for iPhone screen.) I make my way over to create an event, however, and JQuery Datepicker does not work. Neither does another feature, which allows users to shorten their last name to an initial (Tom Smith >> Tom S.) without a page refresh. The code for the latter feature is here:

```
<div class="profile-present">
  <div id="profile-profile_name">
    <h1>
      <p>
        <%= @profile.user.full_name %>
      </p>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <hr />

  <strong>About</strong>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_profile_path(@profile) if @profile.user == current_user %>
  <p>
    <%= current_profile.about %>
  </p>

  <% if @profile.user == current_user %>
    <p>
      <div class="checkbox"><label><%= check_box_tag :toggle_profile_shorten_last_name, "1", current_profile.shorten_last_name? %> <%= Profile.human_attribute_name(:shorten_last_name) %></label></div>
    </p>
  <% end %>

  <% if @profile.user == current_user %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_profile_path(current_profile) %> |
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to 'Back to Profiles', profiles_path %>

  <hr />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('change', '#toggle_profile_shorten_last_name', function() {
    $.ajax('<%= toggle_shorten_last_name_path %>', {
      method: 'PATCH',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#profile-profile_name p').text(data.name);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

As I mentioned, the site is in Bootstrap "Responsive" mode from the beginning. However, if there are any errors on submissions, or the user presses the back button on Safari, the site goes into "desktop" view. Everything works perfectly fine across all major browsers we've tested when in "desktop" view, even on mobile Safari. Just not in "Responsive" mode.

Perhaps it is related to the instability of the Bootstrap in responsive mode? (In my implementation, since it reverts to desktop view sometimes.)

Thus, the two separate pages are not working, events new.html.erb, and profile.html.erb, in Bootstrap responsive.

Some screenshots of what I mean: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s7k9arftKgyMnzUFYmz4mUIhm6Z6bfxehtO9JL9Y-8w/edit

I had to fix just one, it would be the name-shortening feature. Any ideas why both are not working?

events.js.coffee

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/

$(document).on('change', '.auto-submit', ->
  $(@).closest('form').submit()

).on('change', '.toggleable-trigger', ->
  trigger = $ @
  checked = trigger.is ':checked'
  targets = trigger.closest('.toggleable').find '.toggleable-target'

  trigger.closest('label').toggleClass 'grey', not checked
  trigger.closest('.toggleable').find('.toggleable-target-overlay').toggleClass 'hide', checked
  targets.prop('disabled', not checked).each ->
    target = $ @
    if checked
      target.val target.data('saved-value')
    else
      target.data('saved-value', target.val()).val ''

  target.filter(':enabled:visible:first').focus().select() if checked

).on 'click', '.toggleable .toggleable-target-overlay', ->
  $(@).closest('.toggleable').find('.toggleable-trigger').click()
  $(@).closest('.toggleable-target-wrapper').find('.toggleable-target:enabled:visible:first').focus().select()


jQuery ->
  $('#event_event_start, .event_invitation_expired_at').datepicker
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'

[...]
```

Comment: have you looked at the JS console in a Dev emulation? If you use a desktop browser like Chrome Canary you can emulate Safari on an iOS device and you'll be able to review any errors that are thrown. It sounds to me like something (whether in your markup or otherwise) is triggering an error in `Bootstrap.js` which is preventing your JS from running at all

Comment: Hi @Leemo, thanks for the feedback. I will look into the doc.ready aspect - I only coded the datepicker, and a friend coded the name abbreviation. I will add code for the datepicker. We used to have turbolinks problems with it, but I made the problems go away mostly (except right after rails s, which nothing happens, but never after that.) --. Just saw 2nd post, will look at Canary as well, thanks.

Comment: The other thing I would suggest re: the name shortening - AJAX is unnecessary. You could do it without a HTTP request to the server (HTTP requests are the single biggest performance drag and you should avoid them when you can) I'll post some code to shorten the name below

Comment: @Leemo, ok, that sounds great, thanks. I am always looking for better ways to do things, I would appreciate that.

Comment: Ah I was just about to ask if the site was live. I will have a look now

Comment: @leemo sorry, password is password :)

Comment: I'm going to move this to chat so we dont clog the comments. I've done some testing and I'll discuss the results there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52248/discussion-between-leemo-and-codewalrus)

Answer (score 0):

For the name shortening component, AJAX is unnecessary (even if you need to `POST` the full name later).

So long as you always start with the full name you can do something like this:

```
//store the full name at page load
var fullname = $("profile-profile_name > h1 > p").text();
//strip whitespace
fullname.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");

$("#toggle_profile_shorten_last_name").on("change", function(e) {
   var checked = $(this).is(":checked");

   $("#profile-profile_name > h1 > p").text(function(index, value) {
       if(checked) {
           return fullname.substring(0, fullname.indexOf(" ") + 2) + ".";
       } else {
           return fullname;
       }
   });
});
```